# Right class structure for Json.Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have the following json code which i want to deserialize to a c# class but i don't know how this class has to look like. I tried to find a answer by using the json.net documentation but i didn't found a sample. This is the json code:

```
"thumbnails": {
  "default": {
    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e0dJWfQHF8Y/default.jpg"
  },
  "medium": {
    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e0dJWfQHF8Y/mqdefault.jpg"
  },
  "high": {
    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e0dJWfQHF8Y/hqdefault.jpg"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole JSON?  A JSON property, such as `thumbnails`, cannot stand on its own.  It must be part of an object (enclosed in braces).  See [JSON.org](http://json.org/).

Comment: I edited my question. The code is only a snippet cause the real json is over 200 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was using a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string,Thumbnail>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
class Thumbnail
{
    public Default @default {get;set;}
    public Medium medium {get;set;}
    public High high {get;set;}
}

class Default
{
    public string url {get;set;}
}

class Medium
{
    public string url {get;set;}
}

class High
{
    public string url {get;set;}
}
```